# Create a small popup and close it in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I'm not sure how to explain it, i want to redirect user to a page but the site requires users to go the homepage first in order to access to other pages (must be cookie related).

so I was thinking on opening a tiny pop up first that loads the homepage then redirect user to the page

```
const redirectUser = (url) => {
  var TheNewWin = window.open(url, 'TheNewpop', 'scrollbars=no,resizable=no,status=no,location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,width=0,height=0,left=-1000,top=-1');
  TheNewWin.blur();

  setTimeout(()=> {
    TheNewWin.close();
    const win = window.open(data, "_blank");
    win.focus();
  }, 1000)
}

redirectUser('testing-site.php')
```

I tried the following code above in react but it doesn't work, when the page loads, it gives the focus to the new popup,  it has to be a popup that the user barely noticed

thank you

Comment: Do you mean a Modal?

Answer (score 1):

Just from another view port, if you wan to set cookies from your home page in your new page you can easily use a 0px image to do that:

```
<img height="0px" width="0px" src="https://yourhomepage/"/>
```

this will save the requested image **url** cookies within that page.